# iOS memory warning in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, memory-management

I user a timer firing a function repeat per 0.1 second to get a UIImage using UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext and assign to the a @IBOutllet weak UImageView.image.(coverImageView)

```
var timer:Timer?

func fireTimer() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true, block: { [weak self] _ in
        self?.lightTheFier()
    })
}

func invalidateTimer() {
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = nil
}

func lightTheFier() {
    var points = [CGPoint]()
    for pin in pins {
        let point = mapView.convert(pin.coordinate, toPointTo: coverImageView)
        points.append(point)
    }
    coverImageView.image = getMaskedImage(points: points, zoomLevel: Int(mapView.zoomLevel()))
}

func getOringinalImageFromPath() -> UIImage{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(coverImageView.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
    let path = UIBezierPath(rect: coverImageView.bounds)
    UIColor.black.setFill()
    path.fill()
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image!
}

func getMaskImageFromPath(points:[CGPoint], scale:CGFloat) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(coverImageView.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
    let radius:CGFloat = 10.0
    UIColor.blue.setFill()
    for point in points {
        let rect = CGRect(x: point.x - (scale*radius/2), y: point.y - (scale*radius/2), width: scale*radius, height: scale*radius)
        let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect)
        path.fill()
    }
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image!
}

func getMaskedImage(points:[CGPoint], zoomLevel:Int) -> UIImage{
    let orImage = getOringinalImageFromPath().cgImage
    let maskImage = getMaskImageFromPath(points: points, scale: CGFloat(zoomLevel)).cgImage
    let mask = CGImage(maskWidth: maskImage!.width, height: maskImage!.height, bitsPerComponent: maskImage!.bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel: maskImage!.bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow: maskImage!.bytesPerRow, provider: maskImage!.dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true)
    let maskRef = orImage?.masking(mask!)
    let image = UIImage(cgImage: maskRef!)
    return image
}
```

All the code above are in a ViewController.swift for test.

It's fine that the memory is increasing during the function is running, what I want is it can release the memory when I invalidate the timer.

How should I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: put the code  which you have try

Comment: I have edited it, thanks!

Comment: In ARC for some variable to be deallocated all variables using that reference need to go out of scope. See where `coverImageView` will go out of scope. A better approach is to request for an image when needed instead of using a timer. So when the image needs to be displayed check if image is already available else get it.

Comment: Hi  user1046037, thanks for your reply. Actually, I have to update the image when the mapView doing any region change(and keep updating the image during the change), however the delegate only provides the will change and did change. Thanks for giving me any suggestion if I can do it better!

Answer (score 0):

You're starting an image context: `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`, but you're never ending it. You need to add `UIGraphicsEndImageContext()` to your `getMaskImageFromPath` and `getOringinalImageFromPath` methods:

```
func getMaskImageFromPath(points:[CGPoint], scale:CGFloat) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(coverImageView.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
    let radius:CGFloat = 10.0
    UIColor.blue.setFill()
    for point in points {
        let rect = CGRect(x: point.x - (scale*radius/2), y: point.y - (scale*radius/2), width: scale*radius, height: scale*radius)
        let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect)
        path.fill()
    }
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext() // Missing this line
    return image!
}
```

Comment: The run loop retains the timer.

Comment: Hi, Dave, after I fixed it and run, it saves a lot of memory! Well, but the memory only increases but never decreases after I keep firing and invalidating the timer, how can I fix it forward?

Comment: Or maybe give me directions to find what the problems are, thank you so much!

Comment: Are you still getting memory warnings? If you're just looking at the memory Instruments is reporting as used, that will often include memory that will be freed later.

Comment: So it is, I am just looking at the memory Instruments as you said, I will keep check it, thanks!!